# alinear elementos de sidenav al centro

Tags: html, css, materialize

tengo un sidenav utilizando materializecss. Necesito que los elementos que se encuentren en la sidenav estén alineados al centro y no arriba; he intentado utilizando los estilos con `display:flex; align-items:center;` y los alinea al centro pero todo junto y no separado con un salto de linea

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
```

```css
.sidenav { display: flex;
   align-items: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
    <li>uno</li>
    <li>dos</li>
    <li>tres</li>
    <li>cuatro</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger">menu</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

¿algo así?
jugué con el `.sidenav li:nth-child(1){margin-top:29%;}` para  darle el centrado 
y le añadi que las listas sean bloques y su texto este en el centro
 `display:block;
   text-align:center;`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
```

```css
.sidenav { display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   display:block;
   text-align:center;
 
 }
 
 .sidenav li:nth-child(1){
   margin-top:29%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
    <li>uno</li>
    <li>dos</li>
    <li>tres</li>
    <li>cuatro</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger">menu</a>
```